# how to delete data from DataSource in c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, combobox, datasource

is it possible to remove the stored data from dataSource. Because i'm trying to access different data on different form. And when I access data it also shows the previous stored data with the new one. [In image 1 i'm accessing number plate of vehicle stored in xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lONBe.jpg)....and in second image
[when i try to access car models it shows car models with number plates as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyBCR.jpg)

Comment: Can you post your code so that we can see what you are doing and what is causing issue?

Comment: code consists of 4 forms, 2 .cs files and 1 xml file, how can i post it here?

Comment: Just post the code where you are binding data to DataSource.

Comment: This is for number plate 
        private void EditPlateBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var categories = dr.Get_Number_Plate();
            EditPlateBox.DataSource = categories;
            
        }

And this code snippet is for vehicle model
        private void AddVehicleToDriver_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var values = datar.Get_Car_Model();
            AddVehicleToDriver.DataSource = values;
        }